# Mount success but property of device mapper that dmsetup create is lost

Tags: filesystems, device-mapper

I tried to create device mapper with dmsetup as followed:

```
dmsetup create error_disk
0 20000 linear /dev/loop0 0
20000 1 error
20001 20959 linear /dev/loop0 20001
```

Then I check with command below:

```
dd if=/dev/mapper/error_disk of=/dev/null bs=1k count=10000  => Result OK
dd if=/dev/mapper/error_disk of=/dev/null bs=1k count=10001  => Result IO error
```

So the result is right as I expected.

But then I mount as follow:

```
mke2fs /dev/mapper/error_disk 
mount /dev/mapper/error_disk  /mnt/
```

I mounted successful. But when I copy the file with size is 20Mb to /mnt/ and copy successful. But I think the coping must to fail because this error disk is error at sector 20000 (10Mb). 
So how can I do to this coping is fail.